# Edit string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my list.

```
a = ['Very good', 'Excellent','Average']
```

I want to edit the list in this way.

```
a = ['Figure 1 : Very good', 'Figure 2 : Excellent', ' Figure 3 : Average']
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What is the specific problem you encountered while trying to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension

- [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) - method adds counter to an iterable and returns it (the enumerate object).

**Ex.**

```
a = ['Very good', 'Excellent', 'Average']
result = ["Figure {} : {}".format(idx, x) for idx, x in enumerate(a, 1)]
print(result)
```

**O/P:**

```
['Figure 1 : Very good', 'Figure 2 : Excellent', 'Figure 3 : Average']
```

Comment: `enumerate` also has a second parameter that is the starting value. So using `enumerate(a, 1)` would eliminate the need for the not-so-beautiful `idx+1`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille  You're right, let me update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, is by using list compression alone. This code will be way simpler.

`a = [ "Figure "+str(i+1)+" : "+a[i] for i in range(len(a))]`

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output. Also, using indices to iterate on a list is generally frowned upon in Python. See `enumerate`.

Comment: I have corrected the code and thanks I'll keep that in mind.